# Setting up a lab with Windows 2003 server and windows 7 clients

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, infrastructure

We are overhauling a lab with new machines with Windows 7 (as clients - around 150 of them). In the current infrastructure we have students logging in using a generic student id (as having individual student accounts doesn't really serve any additional purpose). This account, as you would imagine is a locked down one that can run a few (age old) softwares required by students in the class. Currently, the individual machines have XP images created by BartPE.
What should be an ideal infrastructure design to cater to such a need with Windows Server 2003 and Windows 7 clients?
It would be great if you can give me pointers to what concepts and background I need to have (like GPO), any design guidelines, best practices?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off looking at something like this:
[Learn how to use native Windows 7 features and free tools from Microsoft to create a steady state on computers running Windows 7.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd641430.aspx)

This will save resources compared to pushing out images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found some good resources at petenetlive ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6KppyXtiDk -step by step nice walk through.